# HTML 5 Storage's same origin policy

Tags: html, local-storage

I've tried with Firefox 4.0 to use the **localStorage** object to save a few values used to fill the form at http://host1.example.com/index.html 
and to fetch those values to automatically fill the same form at http://host2.example.com/index.html but it doesn't work.

Does the same origin policy applies to the url instead of the domain?

Answer (score 6):

No, it applies to [hosts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  You could try setting [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain) before you create or retrieve your `localStorage` objects:

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

--edit

OK, though you can set `document.domain` that has no impact on `localStorage`.  It is possible to hack together a solution using `iframe` and [cross document messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging): [Cross-domain localStorage](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/)

Comment: you can't change the document.domain

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I didn't realize you could drop subdomains.  Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 2):

you're out of luck.  localStorage cannot be shared between different domains.

Answer (score 0):

So for example I could set localStorage data at dev.blah.com, and retrieve it from prod.blah.com, as long as I set the document.domain = "blah.com"; ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use localStorage or sessionStorage cross the domains or sub-domains just with the original API. You can use some libraries to help sending message between different domains.